# Argument is not passed to simple, powershell function

Tags: windows, function, powershell, profile

I decided to make my life easier and try to understand declaring powershell functions.
That is why I created one in .ps1 file following first minutes of this video [Youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=83Di4IgK-VI).

Unfortunately the function does not seem to work properly and I am not sure what is the cause. The
first (and only argument) is not being passed as intended.

*body of the function*

```
function Display-Message($yourmessage){
    echo "Starting function"
    Write-Host "Your message is $yourmessage"
}
```

*output in powershell console*

```
PS C:\Users\marcin> dir function:dis*

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Function        Display-Message


PS C:\Users\marcin> Display-Message "Hello there"
Starting function
Your message is
PS C:\Users\marcin>
```

Can anyone see what am I doing wrong?

[EDIT] After I simply pasted this exact function into terminal, now it works.
Does anyone knows what is the cause of such difference in behaviour?

[EDIT2] Here is the whole $PROFILE file.

```
Set-PSReadLineOption -Colors @{ String = 'Cyan' }
Set-Alias make mingw32-make


# The commands to import.
$commands = "awk", "emacs", "grep", "head", "less", "ls", "man", "sed", "seq", "ssh", "tail", "vim"

# Register a function for each command.
$commands | ForEach-Object { Invoke-Expression @"
# Remove-Alias $_ -Force -ErrorAction Ignore

# function Locate([string]$FilePart)
# {
#   Get-Childitem –Path C:\ -Include $FilePart -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
# }

function Siema{
    $SIEMA = "SIEMA"
    echo siema
}

function Display-Message($yourmessage){
    echo "Starting function"
    Write-Host "Your message is $yourmessage"
}


function global:$_() {
    for (`$i = 0; `$i -lt `$args.Count; `$i++) {
        # If a path is absolute with a qualifier (e.g. C:), run it through wslpath to map it to the appropriate mount point.
        if (Split-Path `$args[`$i] -IsAbsolute -ErrorAction Ignore) {
            `$args[`$i] = Format-WslArgument (wsl.exe wslpath (`$args[`$i] -replace "\\", "/"))
        # If a path is relative, the current working directory will be translated to an appropriate mount point, so just format it.
        } elseif (Test-Path `$args[`$i] -ErrorAction Ignore) {
            `$args[`$i] = Format-WslArgument (`$args[`$i] -replace "\\", "/")
        }
    }

    if (`$input.MoveNext()) {
        `$input.Reset()
        `$input | wsl.exe $_ (`$args -split ' ')
    } else {
        wsl.exe $_ (`$args -split ' ')
    }
}
"@
}
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. What is the function definition (check `(Get-Command Display-Message).Definition`), and what version of PowerShell are you using? How did you define the function? Did you paste it into the terminal, import it from a module, or dot source a containing script file?

Comment: Smells like one of the two variables is misspelled. Make sure they're both `$yourmessage`.

Comment: PS C:\Users\marcin> (Get-Command Display-Message).Definition
        echo "Starting function"
        Write-Host "Your message is "

Comment: I put it in the profile.ps1 file ,and then run new session of powershell.

Comment: Rename body as `Display-Message2` and run it as `Display-Message2 "Hello there"` , i hope this will help you get message `The term is not recognized`. This sould mean you did't `run` your function

Comment: There was only your function in `$PSHOME\Profile.ps1` ?

Comment: Just to be sure I run the .ps1 script (which is default $PROFILE value), and the function could not receive its argument. On the other hand, after pasting exactly same code now it prints the arguments that is given. There are also other functions there.

Comment: @Fly_37 Your profile is only loaded on startup, if you make changes to the file and want them reflected in an existing shell, try `. $profile`

Comment: I guess it's more about `Invoke-Expression @"`.

Comment: I won't post an answer as to me variable substitution in shell script (and PowerShell is a shell script) should not require explanation.

Answer (score 0):

As @TheMadTechnician states that the answer should "solve" the question :

The problem comes from the fact that all your functions in your `Profile.ps1` are defined through `Invoke-Expression` with a quoted script block as parameter, more precisely the PowerShell way for an "*here document*". In that case there is variable substitution first applied by the shell before the `Invoke-Expression` cmdlet receives the input as the script uses double quoted here-doc with  `@"`. That means that you have to escape your variables with backticks (`̀` , see them before the `$` signs) for this function in your `Profile.ps1` :

```
function Display-Message(`$yourmessage){
    echo "Starting function"
    Write-Host "Your message is `$yourmessage"
}
```

It should then behave normally once you've restarted your PowerShell session.

Alternatively, you can also change the *here document* quoting to single quote (`@' ... '@`) instead of double one (`@" ... "@`), beware that you have then to update the whole expression as all the current backtick escaped variables will be then read *literally* , so you have to remove backticks from all the `` `$ `` in `global:$_` for example and need to adapt so it does not require variable expansion for the un-escaped ones.